# How can I view a PDF in 2-up?

Tags: pdf

Is there a way to view PDFs on Android that lets you show 2-up like a regular book? - or like the 2-up option on desktop Acrobat Reader (with first page as cover)?

Comment: I assume you mean that it displays two pages at a time?

Comment: Yes, similar to what Acrobat lets you do for "book style" reading on the PC

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [EBookDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ebookdroid) has this functionality.

The PDF reader in Documents To Go looks like it might, too.